# Rewrites not working properly in Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My intention is to redirect `https://example.com/admin` to my firebase function named `admin`. So I have the following code in the `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/admin{,/**}",
        "function": "admin"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've followed the instructions from this website: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Using my browser, if I go to `https://my-server-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/admin` everything works an looks fine. But if I go to `https://example.com/admin`, this is what I get instead:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is your function deployed in `us-central1`? Firebase Hosting currently only supports that region.

Comment: no, actually is on europe. I'm going to change it